# MySQLite Database results not being printed out

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

After inserting rows in my database table and trying to fetch them to display, I get a blank activity. It puzzles me because it used to work a month ago but not anymore.
I even went through this [tutorial link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) to learn more, but it was all in vain.
Below is the section for the constructors for the database table:

```
// Emptry constructor
public Contact() {

}

// Constructor
public Contact(int _contactid, String contactphone, String contactlmp) {
    this._contactid = _contactid;
    this.contactphone = contactphone;
    this.contactlmp = contactlmp;
}

// Constructor
public Contact(String contactphone, String contactlmp) {
    this.contactphone = contactphone;
    this.contactlmp = contactlmp;
}
```

Below is the database function I use to retrieve all the elements in a table:

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + ";";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if(c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();

    // Loop through all rows and add to list
    while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.set_contactid(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)));
        contact.setContactphone(c.getString(1));
        contact.setContactlmp(c.getString(2));

        contactList.add(contact);

        c.moveToNext();
    }

    return contactList;
}
```

And below is the call to this function, which uses the results to print them out on that activity. This is embedded in a thread placed in the activity's onCreate() function:

```
contacts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contacts);
dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
            int i = 1;
            dbContacts = dbHandler.getAllContacts();
            for(Contact cn : dbContacts) {
                dbString += i + "    " + cn.getContactphone() + "    " + cn.getContactlmp() + "\n";
                i++;
            }
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.start();
    contacts.setText(dbString);
```

And below are the getter and setter methods for the database contacts, which work when used in another context of the same application:

```
// Getter and Setter methods
public int get_contactid() {
    return _contactid;
}

public void set_contactid(int _contactid) {
    this._contactid = _contactid;
}

public String getContactlmp() {
    return contactlmp;
}

public void setContactlmp(String contactlmp) {
    this.contactlmp = contactlmp;
}

public String getContactphone() {
    return contactphone;
}

public void setContactphone(String contactphone) {
    this.contactphone = contactphone;
}
```

What might I be doing wrong? Why did it suddenly stop working?

Comment: If you modified your database content.. like tables, row and columns. then you need to change your database name and database version.

Comment: I hadn't modified my database content, but i tried as you suggested though but got nothing

Comment: While reading from table, we need to call SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: Tried that but nothing still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. I tried to make changes to the UI from a worker thread and that's why I got no results. I had to use a handler and a worker thread to do the database queries and update the UI as shown below:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            int i = 1;
            dbContacts = dbHandler.getAllContacts();
            for(Contact cn : dbContacts) {
                dbString += i + "    " + cn.getContactphone() + "    " + cn.getContactlmp() + "\n";
                i++;
            }
            contacts.setText(dbString);
        }
    };

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Any Error log, or did u make any db change(Structure wise)

```
contacts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contacts);
dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
            int i = 1;
            dbContacts = dbHandler.getAllContacts();
            for(Contact cn : dbContacts) {
                dbString += i + "    " + cn.getContactphone() + "    " + cn.getContactlmp() + "\n";
                i++;
            }
            contacts.setText(dbString);
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.start();
```

Comment: No error log, and I made no db change. when i try to retrieve the last contact using the following code it works though: public String getPhone() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE 1;";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (c == null)
            return null;
        c.moveToLast();
        String phone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_COLUMN_PHONE));
        try {
            return phone;
        } finally {
            c.close();
            db.close();
        }
    }